# what is the smd equivalent package of BD139 transistor?

Tags: transistors, surface-mount

I am developing a basic switching circuit using a PIC microcontroller where the maximum drive current will be up to 2A in this case I was using BD139 but now due to my PCB has a Single-layer option I have to use SMD for it. so, please anyone suggest to me the best NPN SMD transistor for my current requirement.

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. As you'll see in the tour, questions on part recommendations are off-topic and this question should be closed, I'm afraid. Again, welcome

Answer (score 2):

> the maximum drive current will be up to 2A in this case I was using
> BD139

The BD139 is a poor choice for switching 2 amps. Its **absolute maximum** DC current rating is only 1.5 amps. In the graph below (from page 3 of the [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/bd139-d.pdf)) we see that it can barely manage 1A with a Base drive current of 50 mA.

[image]

So instead of trying to find an equivalent of the BD139 you should look for a transistor that meets your design requirements. Its absolute maximum ratings should be well above what you need (eg. at least double the current rating and 20% higher voltage rating). You should check the saturation voltage and drive current requirements, bearing in mind that the datasheet may only show the *typical* (not minimum) performance characteristics.

If you are driving the transistor directly from the PIC then a MOSFET may be more appropriate. Make sure the recommended Gate drive voltage is low enough (eg. 4.5 V if the PIC is powered with 5 V, 2.5 V if it is powered by 3.3 V). The MOSFET's current rating should be *much* higher than 2 A (eg. 10 A) to avoid excessive voltage drop and overheating.

Once you have determined the specifications you need, find suitable transistors using the 'parametric search' function on your supplier's website.